# Capture picture from webcam Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, webcam

I came across this tutorial here:
https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/blob/master/s/webrtc-capturestill/capture.js

However I am having trouble implementing it into my code and was looking for some assistance...

I basically want to have a panel where you can press a 'take picture' button. This will then open up a new floating panel where the live stream of the webcam will start automatically and you have a button which captures the image.

```
    takePicture: function (photoPanel)
    {
        let me = this;

        let capture = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Take Picture',
            height: 500,
            width: 750,
            draggable: true,
            closable: true,
            floating: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                pack: 'center',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'video',
                    height: 400,
                    width: 350
  // this is where I want the live webcam to stream
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Take Picture',
                    itemId: 'startbutton',
                    handler: function (btn)
                    {

                    }
    // button to capture the image
                }
            ]
        });
        photoPanel.add(capture).show();
    },
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the problem ? In `takePicture` function you need to start `getUserMedia` and set stream callback to `video` container. On `startbutton` button you need just to create canvas from stream.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33vi) with capturing photos based on provided scripts

Comment: Appreciate this thanks! Just a quick question, towards the end of the code where it says 'photo.setAttribute('src', data);  - the 'photo' says 'unresolved variable', what should this be? Thanks

Comment: forgot to delete it

Comment: Sorry for another question, but I've noticed when I click the button to actually take the picture - for some reason it displays a low resolution image?

Comment: I think it depends on the ratio of two values -  the camera resolution and the size of the container for the image. Try resizing the container